# Refactor Ruby on Rails snippets

Tags: ruby, refactoring, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Association between `Account` and `user` is one to many
`Account has many Users`

I need to do something in account model method which needs user object.

Right now, I'm doing like:

`User.first.account.get_something(User.first)`

But It doesn't seems to be good practice.

How could I refactor above.

Comment: I think the `get_something` method should be placed in `User` instead of `Account`

Answer (score 0):

That code seems a very roundabout way of going from one to the other... and then back again.

As ShiningRay suggests - you probably need to move the method out of account into user.

```
class User
  def get_something
    do_stuff(self.account)
  end
end
```

Then you can just call: User.first.get_something

Alternatively you could use this:

```
u = User.first
u.account.get_something(u)
```

But it just feels like feature-envy.

Comment: Beware, if that `get_something` method relies on `Account` data, then you'll be introducing a strong coupling between `User` and `Account`, which could be avoided. If `Account belongs_to :user`, then `Account` would be able to access `self.user` transparently.

Comment: @Romain - as mentioned in the question, an account has many users... so self.user will not work from within an account.

Comment: you're right - I forgot that. I'm still skeptical about the coupling it generates, would need to know what `get_something`actually is. Also a bit puzzled by the "account has many users" scenario - seems odd to me, but maybe I'm just stubborn.

Comment: No matter what get_something does, I can tell that by the very nature of accounts... users and account are always going to be tightly linked. There are going to be many different methods where the two models interact - there's no getting around it... just ways of making it less painful :)